# Error Rendering Control in aspx of home page. An unhandled exception has occurred. HtmlImageID property is not specified

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net . I am getting the error rendering contol- Header1.
An unhandled exception has occurred. HtmlImageID property is not specified.

How to fix this error?

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 100%; text-align: left; border-top-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-left-color: black; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-bottom-color: black; border-top-color: black; border-right-width: 0px; border-right-color: black; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px;" valign="top">
        <uc2:Header ID="Header1" runat="server" OnLoad="Header1_Load" EnableTheming="true" EnableViewState="true" Visible="true" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

My uc2 is

```
<%@ Register Src="controls/Header.ascx" TagName="Header" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
```

Code Behind :

```
protected void Header1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to give us more information in order to help you. What is the code that throws the exception...

Comment: Thanks for posting your code! When you paste code into your question hightlight it and click the `{}` button in the tool bar.  This will format it and make it more readable.  Can you please post all information related to the custom user control `uc2`? I suspect we will need to look at the inner workings of this to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<uc2:Header` tag you will need to specify a value for `HtmlImageID`. What this value needs to be is hard to say without seeing the details of uc2.